# Using Npm as a build tool for different configurations

Tags: javascript, npm

I am creating a simple JavaScript library. Its purpose is to do some operation on a iframe element hit a URL and load the result into the iframe. it's a single JS file.

While developing locally I want the `host_url` to be `localhost` but when I distribute it to others i want the `host_url` to be `mysite.api.com`. I think this step should be a part of build step. I am choosing `npm` as a build tool.

But when I make a google search for managing configurations for local & prod systems using npm scripts, I do not get any relevant results. How can I do this?

Here is the `package.json`:

```
  1 {
  2   "name": "index.js",
  3   "version": "1.0.0",
  4   "description": "",
  5   "main": "v8p.js",
  6   "config": {
  7         "host_url" : "localhost" //----> ??? 
  8    },
  9   "scripts": {
 10     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
 11     "dev-buil": "" //---> what command should be used here to change setting in index.js using the values provided in host_url
 12   },
 13   "author": "",
 14   "license": "ISC"
 15 }
~
```

Answer (score 0):

`Use something like node-convict to manage your configuration variables for development, and production etc. Go through its README.md file for better idea.`

Use [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify) to require the appropriate config file in browser and set host_url variable.

Comment: i am not using node .  i have a single js file that has to loded into broswer . The example on README.md page has an example of server side js file

Comment: @anekix I have updated my answer since I got your exact requirement now.

Comment: i tried using browserify but i cant fit it into my purpose. suppose i have a varibale `url="localhost"` how can i build a js file which has `url="mysite.com" ` before i can distribute my lib to others